# Jquery UI Google CSS, from where?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here's the site I'm having problems with:

http://www.ashleymosuro.com/newsite/about

For some reason, my custom theme I created for the Jquery UI is being overridden by the google hosted stylesheet, and I have no idea where in my theme it is referencing the stylesheet. Wherever it is, I need to get rid of it. I'm trying to style the progress bars in the sidebar so that they are 20px high. I have done this in my custom theme stylesheet but it just keeps being overridden.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try and use the correct syntax in the stylesheet:

`/* jQuery UI Progressbar 1.8.13*/
/* Progress bars on about page*/
.ui-progressbar.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-all { 
    height:20px;
    text-align: left;
    }`

(i don't know where the google css comes from. and excuse the way the code is presented; the 'code' button seems to be out-of-order)

Comment: Awesome, that worked. It would be great to know what is calling the Google css though..thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Google CDN jQuery UI stylesheet is loading after your themes CSS so it will override any of your styles.

Your also getting a 404 for `http://ashleymosuro.com/newsite/css/jquery-ui.css?ver=3.1.3`

The Google CDN CSS is being enqueued with `wp_enqueue_style` with the handle `custom-datefield-style-css`.  You should be able to remove it from functions.php or it might be in header.php

Comment: That's odd...as I'm referencing it like this:

wp_register_style( 'jqueryUiStyle', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/css/jquery-ui.css', true);

in my functions.php. In my styles.css I also have @import "css/jquery-ui.css";

Comment: Sorry for the double comment but I still can't find the google css link? Not in functions.php